# Integers values of composite type become null at WCF operation

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a strange behavior with WCF service and c#; I am trying to send a complex type [FooRequest] to service operation; [FooRequest] has some properties and one of them is a user define type [MyType] which has only simple properties as strings and integers.

Now, when client pass [FooRequest] object including y, server receive it with full parameters except integers and decimals inside [MyType]. Could you help me with that.

Contracts of the Service:

```
[DataContract]
public enum MessageType
{
    [EnumMember]
    REQ1,
    [EnumMember]
    REQ2        
}

[MessageContract]
public class MyType 
{        
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public decimal DecValue { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class FooRequest
{        
    [MessageHeader]
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public MessageType SomeEnum { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public List<MyType> SomeObject { get; set; }
}
```

at client side:

```
        Svc.FooServiceClient client = new Svc.FooServiceClient();
        FooRequest req = new Svc.FooRequest()
        {
            FooId = 1,
            SomeEnum = MessageType.REQ1,
            SomeObject = (new List<MyType>() { new Svc.MyType() { Title = "txt txt", DecValue = 23.5, IntValue = 500 }}).ToArray()
        };
        FooResponse res = client.MyOperation(req );
```

at server side

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public FooResponse MyOperation(FooRequest request)
    {
       /*
        request.FooId = 1
        request.SomeEnum  = REQ1
        request.SomeObject.Length = 1
        request.SomeObject[0].Title = "txt txt"
        request.SomeObject[0].DecValue = null ????!!!! here is the problem
        request.SomeObject[0].IntValue = null ????!!!! here is the problem
       */
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that when I change [SomeEnum] to be simple type (i.e int or string), everything working fine. if I change it to enum, the problem appears again.

Comment: Also, If I change the decoration of enum property [SomeEnum] to be MessageBodyMember insteade of MessageHeader, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of some one face the same problem, I found a solution for this issue. Adding  [XmlSerializerFormat] decoration to the service Interface with [ServiceContract] will solve the problem. I think that is a some kind of conflict problem with serialization.

Comment: Greetings to you, you solved the problem that I was stuck with for several days. thank you @};-

Answer (score 0):

You decorated your types incorrectly. Instead of

```
[MessageContract]
public class FooRequest
{        
    [MessageHeader]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
```

It should be

```
[DataContract]
public class FooRequest
{        
    [DataMember]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
```

Do the same for MyType. So you simply have to change the attributes.

Comment: You are right, when I change decoration to DataContract it works fine. Unfortunately, I can't change it in real code since I have to send customized SOAP message. So I am stuck with MessageContract. any other solution ?